# Getting non-zero data position from csv file_Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with data like this:

[image]

Is there any method that I can get the positions of all of the non-zero data with Python?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with following code.

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', newline='\n') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    row_id = 1
    for col_val in spamreader:
        # Moving through each Row
        col = 1
        for val in col_val:
            # Moving through Column
            if int(val) > 0:
                # Non zero value found, print location
                print("Row: "+str(row_id)+", Col: "+str(col))

            col += 1

        row_id += 1
```

test.csv is your csv file.